# Python store list by using for loop

Tags: python

How do I store all lists into new lists?
1. Random some lists

```
import random
randomlist = []
range1 = int(input('enter range one'))
range2 = int(input('enter range two'))
for i in range(range1,range2):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)
    print(randomlist)
```

2. Store the lists that generated by the code up there into list_x.
   x will increase 1 each time. so will be list_1, list_2, list_3.........list_x
   the list_1, list_2, list_3.........list_x can be used in future code.

For example: generate 3 lists

```
[21]
[21, 18]
[21, 18, 1]
```

These lists will be store into list_x and will get

```
list_1=[21]
list_2=[21,18]
list_3=[21,18,1]
```

Comment: You don't want dynamic variable names. You might think you need them but you don't. Use a list to store those lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import random

 totalList = []
 randomlist = []
 range1 = int(input('enter range one'))
 range2 = int(input('enter range two'))
 for i in range(range1,range2):
     n = random.randint(1,30)
     randomlist.append(n)
     print(randomlist)

     totalList.append(randomlist.copy())

 print(totalList)
```

Comment: That's the way to go, but some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `globals()['list_'+str(i)] = randomlist.copy()` in your for loop. Using this you create a copy of the randomlist and save it as `list_X` depending on the iterator.